# Inputting strings into arrayLists?

Tags: java, arrays, xcode, arraylist

Suppose that I have a code empList and it is an ArrayList.  I have 3 Strings,  name, boss, and dob  holding the data for some employee.  I want to write code that creates an Employee from my Strings and then adds it to the empList. I can use the add method of ArrayList to add my employee after I have constructed it, but I'm not too sure how.

This is my Employee class I have written so far:

```
ArrayList<String> empList = new ArrayList<String>();
class Employee{
    Employee(String dob, String name, String boss)  //(constructor)
   //dob should be mm/dd/yyyy, and boss of length 0 indicates no boss.

   int    getAge()
   String getName()
   String getBoss()  //returns length 0 string if none
   String getDob()
```

Comment: Why is it a list of `String`s, and not a list of `Employee`s?

Comment: Shouldn't `empList` be a list of `Employee`s?

Comment: Isn't it? Does it make a difference whether I write "String" or "Employee"? I've only been programming for 3 weeks so these norms are a bit new to me.

Comment: Do you want to create one `Employee` for each `ArrayList<String>`s? Or do you want to create one `String` for each `Employee` and put those `String`s into your `ArrayList<String>`?

Comment: Yes it makes a big difference wether you use an `ArrayList<String>` or an `ArrayList<Employee>`. **The compiler** won't let you add an `Employee e = new Employee("asdf","qwer","yxcv");` into a string list and it also won't let you add an `String s = "uiop"` into an employee list.

Answer (score 0):

You should change the List declaration to `List<Emloyee>`:

```
List<Emloyee> empList = new ArrayList<Emloyee>();
```

(read more about generics in Java: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/)

Then you can create a new Employee instance and add it to the list:

```
Employee employee = new Employee("dob", "John Smith", "His Boss");
empList.add(employee);
```

By the way: consider changing the type of `boss` from `String` to `Employee` (depending on you use case/meaning).

Comment: Your link doesn't work yet ;) some alien underscore?

Comment: @isi Please try now, it was indeed due to underscore character, corrected now.

Comment: May I ask how when you use your 2nd code how we actually input new employees? In my main method would I just write employee("June-10-2014","Dariusz","user3727184");

Comment: @user3727184 I have problems to understand what you are trying to achieve. Can we first try to make this clear? The first question would be. Do you want to make strings out of employees or do you want to make employees out of strings?

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to do it in your constructor using

```
empList.add(this);
```

However, you'd have to change the type of your `ArrayList` to `Employee`, or if you wanted to keep it as a `String`, then you'd have to create a `String` in your constructor, and do

```
String str = "Your string here";
empList.add(str);
```

I'm also pretty sure that you can't have your `ArrayList` outside of your class. Java doesn't let you have things outside of classes.

Answer (score -1):

You can add strings to the `ArrayList` by it's `add()` method.

You already have the getXXX() methods in your employee class, so you can simply do something along the lines of

```
String str = "Name: " + emp.getName() + ", Boss: " + emp.getBoss() + ", DoB: " + emp.getDoB();

empList.add(str);
```

What you probably want is an ArrayList of Employees (`ArrayList<Employee>`), which would be added in a similar manner, without adding everything to a string.

Comment: Creating Strings using '+' operator is poor programming practice, use StringBuilder or String.concatenate() function instead.

Comment: @ike_love I wasn't going to add unnecessary complexity to a brand new programmer. Don't think it warrants a downvote in these circumstances, but to each their own I suppose.